# Как создать и открыть в новой вкладке html страницу с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html

Я хотел бы создать новую страницу на js при клике, и открыть ее в новой вкладке, как можно такое сделать?

Comment: <a target="_blank">...</a> даже js не нужен

Comment: @kah3vich и что оно откроет? где писать разметку?

Comment: при нажатие на эту ссылку она открывает указанную страницу в новой вкладке

Comment: @kah3vich ссылку из href?

Comment: <a href="test.com" target="_blank">...</a>

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно создать страницу с нуля на лету, можете попробовать так, хотя это будет странно и неожиданно для пользователя (и может быть блокировано настройками или средствами борьбы с всплывающими окнами):

```js
const html = `
  <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>
    <p>Text.</p>
  </body>`;

window.open('about:blank').document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
```

Раньше можно было использовать [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), но теперь браузеры запрещают навигацию верхнего уровня по таким адресам из скриптов.